# Tips for evaluating $P(X\gt Y\gt Z)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, expectation

Does anyone know of any references for how to evaluate stochastic
inequalities? Surprisingly, I can't find any good references for general
problems.

For example, suppose we have three random variables, $X,$ $Y$, $Z$.
What can we learn about inequalities like $P(X>Y>Z)$ supposing the
variables are i) identically distributed but not independent, ii) independent, or iii) simply  $iid$?

A first step I thought of was to write expressions like

\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \int_{x}\int_{y}\int_{z}1\{X-Y>0,Y-Z>0\}f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)dy dx dz
\end{eqnarray*}

If $X,Y,Z$ are independent then we can write expressions like:

\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \int_{x}\int_{y}\int_{z}1\{X-Y>0,Y-Z>0\}f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y)f_{Z}(z)dydxdz
\end{eqnarray*}

But I don't know what this gives me. Would a change of variables be of use? Thanks. I hope my question isn't too vague.

Edit: Basically, I want to argue statements
like $P(X>Y)$$=P(Y>X)$ if $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is symmetric in its arguments.

Comment: Can you give a specific example of what you mean by evaluating stochastic inequalities? Do you mean a stochastic analogue to the likes of Young's inequality, Holder's inequality?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the response. Basically, I want to argue statements like $P(X>Y)$$=P(Y<X)$ if $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is symmetric in its arguments.

Comment: ^Should be P(X>Y)=P(Y>X)

Comment: Each $1\{X-Y>0,Y-Z>0\}$ should read $1\{x-y>0,y-z>0\}$. You may also omit the indices to the integral signs.

Answer (score 0):

The distribution of $(X,Y)$ is symmetric when the distributions of $(X,Y)$ and $(Y,X)$ coincide. Expectations depend only on distributions hence this implies $E(H(X,Y))=E(H(Y,X))$ for every measurable function $H$. If $H:(x,y)\mapsto\mathbf 1_{x\lt y}$, one gets $P(X\lt Y)=P(Y\lt X)$.

Likewise, if the distribution of $(X,Y,Z)$ is symmetric, $P(X\gt Y\gt Z)=P(Y\gt Z\gt X)$ which is also equal to 4 other probabilities of similar events.

When there is no tie, that is, when the event $[X=Y]\cup[Y=Z]\cup[Z=X]$ has probability zero, $[X\gt Y\gt Z]$ and the 5 similar other events yield a partition of the probability space hence these considerations yield $P(X\gt Y\gt Z)=\frac16$. Otherwise, one can only be sure that $P(X\gt Y\gt Z)\leqslant\frac16$.

The setting where this applies includes $(X,Y,Z)$ being i.i.d. with no atom but also less restrictive situations such that $(X,Y,Z)$ being exchangeable.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you.